# Differences between Boost.Coroutine and Boost.Coroutine2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-coroutine, boost-coroutine2

What are the main differences between [Boost.Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) and [Boost.Coroutine2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/index.html) ?

Comment: Does the documentation truly neglect to mention it?

Comment: I think it can be deduced by comparing the overview sections; I'm asking here to get an answer from somebody who knows the differences better than I would do by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some differences:

- Boost.Coroutine2 requires C++11
- Boost.Coroutine provides symmetric and asymmetric coroutines, Boost.Coroutine2 only provides asymmetric coroutines.

Comment: Are you aware of any other differences other than these ?

Comment: No, I am not aware of anything major, but I would not expect any other noticeable differences – especially since the documentations are essentially copy-pasted with _very_ minor changes. I cannot give you a more definitive answer though.

Comment: I was also looking for the differences and your answer confirms what I found once more. +1

Comment: why coroutine2 only provides asymmetric coroutines?

Answer (score 10):

- boost.coroutine2 is the follow-up project of boost.coroutine (boost.coroutine will be marked as deprecated soon)
- boost.coroutine2 uses class execution_context from boost.context
- boost.coroutine is implemented with the deprecated C-like fcontext-API from boost.context