# What is the difference between boost's "coroutine" and "coroutine 2" in terms of performance and generated binaries?

Tags: c++, boost

The documentation for [boost::coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) and [boost::coroutine 2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/index.html) looks very similar.

The only difference I could make out, is that coroutine 2 needs C++14 whereas coroutine does not, and that coroutine has symetric and asymmetric coroutines. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343873/differences-between-boost-coroutine-and-boost-coroutine2).

So is there actually a difference in terms of expressive power and performance between the two? Should I always use coroutine 2 if I am using C++14?